# Is Email Sync between a Hosted Exchange and CRM Online Server Side Sync supported?

Tags: dynamics-crm, exchange-server, dynamics-crm-online, server-side-sync

I'm looking to establish synchronization between a hosted Exchange and Dynamics CRM Online.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, please see: [Set up server-side synchronization of email, appointments, contacts, and tasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531109.aspx)

Comment: If by "Hosted" you mean "partner hosted" which is effectively Exchange on-premises, then yes, in CRM 2016 Online Spring Update Release Service Pack 1 or whatever the hell they are calling it this time round.